# Neo4j Spring ogm causes stackoverflow for followers-followings concept

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Trying to implement simple social network concept: followers + followings. All are just Accounts related to each other. Using Neo4j and Spring boot.

```
'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
```

**Account.class**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Account {

  @Id
  private String pk;

  @Relationship(type = "FOLLOWS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  private Set<Account> followers;

  @Relationship(type = "FOLLOWS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
  private Set<Account> followings;
}
```

Using standart spring `CrudRepository` (or `Neo4JRepository`, no difference) i constantly get stackoverflows working with accounts. Simplest situation where `A` follows `B` and `B` follows `A` will cause a SOF for `findById()`. I understand that it has smth. to do with fetching depth, but it defaults to 1, which means that i should get `followers` and `followings` of account but theirs relations should be empty. The relations work correctly in terms of adding: i can connect accounts from any end by adding to appropriate `Set` and graph turns out exactly as i intend, but fetching is not working..

**Main question:** What am i doing and understanding wrong, and what can be done to implement this kind of relations correctly?

I tried using `session.load()` with depth 0, and no SOFs, of course, but that is not exactly what i need. Default depth  `1` should provide exactly what i need, but i guess i misunderstand the concept?

**And extra**: is there a way to configure default depth for entire application? Without using `session` manually, thus reimplementing all basic operations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got it. The real problem was not in fetching, but inside internal call for `equals()` and `hashcode()` somewhere during fetch. Since i use **lombok** with `@Data`, all properties paricipated in those methods, causing SOF.

Adding `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"followers", "followings"})` to class's annotations fixed the issue and depth=1 works now.